# Actionscript MouseEvent

Tags: actionscript-3, event-handling

I have a MouseEvent function and I need to call it without MouseEvent as well. I know there is quick and easy way to do it but I forgot....

```
my_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, callEvent);
function callEvent(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("Mouse event called");
}
```

> callEvent()???

now I need to call the same event without any events. I know I can create a new function without any event an call that from callEvent. But that is not what I am looking for...

Thanks,
Rex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the function simply insert null in the braces

Like that-

CallEvent(null);

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily like this (put "**= null**" after the event arg):

```
my_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, callEvent);
function callEvent(e:MouseEvent = null):void
{
    trace("Mouse event called");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I know that I did it little bit different way but this one is even better... :)

Answer (score 0):

from [this](http://flexcomps.wordpress.com/2008/04/29/dispatching-custom-events-in-as3-with-data-or-object/):

`dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.ONLOADED, data ));`